# Prove this inequality concerning integral average.

Tags: analysis

Let $f\in L^1([a,b])$, and extend $f$ to be $0$ outside $[a,b]$. Let
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f
$$

How to prove
$$
\int_a^b\left | \phi\right | \leqslant\int_a^b\left|f\right|
$$

---

To @martini:

I asked this question because I find something strange: if we let $f(x)=x^2$, then $\phi(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{3}h^2$, so the inequality doesn't hold apparently.

Clearly, the problem is I do not extend $f$ to be $0$ outside $[a,b]$, so $\phi$ should be smaller near $a$ and $b$. However, when I put this example into your proof, I cannot figure out what goes wrong. It seems you have proved 
$$
\int_a^b(x^2+\frac{1}{3}h^2) \leqslant\int_a^b x^2
$$

I think the problem lies in your exchange of $\chi$, but still not clear.

Comment: Expand the expression for $\phi$, and then interchange the order of integration.

Comment: @WillieWong, please refer to my update in the post.

Comment: The corrections due to the edge terms are quite large compared to $h^2$. For $k < h$ and $x = b-k$ you have $$\phi(x) = \frac{k + h}{2h} x^2 - \frac{h^2 - k^2}{2h} x + \frac{1}{6h}(h^3 + k^3) $$ As you wrote, what you plugged in as "$\phi$" is not really the correct function. If you plug in the correct function you will not see a contradiction.

Comment: @WillieWong, my point is exactly where the proof given by martini shows the condition *$f$ equals 0 outside [a,b]*? If I still let  $f(x)=x^2$ outside $[a,b]$, it seems the proof can pass as well. i.e., consider two function $\tilde f$ and $\hat f$, the former is extended to be zero and the latter is extended to still be $x^2$, then put them into the proof, replace $f$ there, what makes the situation of $\hat f$ fails?

Comment: @WillieWong, in the situation of $\hat f$, it should fail, for the reason shown in my update. But the proof seems to work fine.

Comment: Ah, the step where it is used is in the third line. If $[x-h,x+h] \subset [a,b]$ then you can change the bounds of integration and add a characteristic function. But if $f$ doesn't vanish outside $[a,b]$ and if either $x-h < a$ or $x+h > b$, that line is false. (In fact, in such a case the third line is going to be less than the second line.)

Comment: @WillieWong, you helped me a lot!!!! I have been confused for a long time....Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have where $\chi_I$ denotes the indicator function of $I$$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
\begin{align*}
  \int_a^b \abs{\phi(x)}\, dx &= \frac 1{2h}\int_a^b \abs{\int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(\xi)\, d\xi}\, dx\\
         &\le \frac 1{2h}\int_a^b \int_{x-h}^{x+h} \abs{f(\xi)}\, d\xi\, dx\\
         &= \frac 1{2h}\int_a^b \int_a^b \abs{f(\xi)}\chi_{[x-h,x+h]}(\xi)\, dx\, d\xi\\
         &= \frac 1{2h}\int_a^b\abs{f(\xi)} \int_a^b \chi_{[\xi-h,\xi+h]}(x)\, dx\,d\xi\\ & \text{note that $x-h \le \xi\le x+h \iff \xi-h\le x \le \xi+h$}\\
         &= \frac 1{2h}\int_a^b\abs{f(\xi)}\int_{\xi-h}^{\xi+h}\, dx\, d\xi\\
         &\le \frac {2h}{2h} \int_a^b \abs{f(\xi)}\, d\xi.
\end{align*}

Comment: I have some confusion, please refer to my update in the post.

Comment: Confusion solved, thanks to Willie Wong:)